# Use installed app's location as a default path during a major upgrade

Tags: windows-installer, installshield

I have an application which I am writing a major upgrade for.
The only thing that is persistent is an `UpgradeCode`.
What I want is to use a location of a previously installed version as a default path for installation.

My naive solution is to run a CustomAction which modifies the `INSTALLDIR` with a variable `APP_LOCATION` obtained by `AppSearch` table.

1. *Is there a conventional way to achive that via means on MSI or InstallShield?*
2. *Can I use a condition in an MSI table to use "APP_LOCATION" from AppSearch table if it contains value?* For example: `INSTALLDIR = APP_LOCATION ? APP_LOCATION : MY_DEFAULT_INSTALL_DIR` (syntax is to emphasize the logic, idk if is valid)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fetch previous install location using the following method:

Msi.GetProductInfo(ProductCode of previous Install, "InstallLocation");

To get the product code of previous installation, Use the public property set for the major upgrade. This public property for example **OLD_PRODUCT_DETECTED** property can be found in ActionProperty column of Upgrade table. It's value will be set to product code({GUID}).

Make sure to call the above method after FindRelatedProducts action which sets the value for public property to {GUID} if previous installation found.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the corresponding page in documentation?

Comment: I found this one. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/sysinfoapi/nf-sysinfoapi-getproductinfo
Personally, I had used c# code using managed code custom action.

Comment: Can you elaborate on getting the product code from an upgrade table? What is the name of the property to query? *When the FindRelatedProducts action detects an affected product installed on the system, it appends the product code to a property specified in the ActionProperty column.* - it doesn't mention the name of the property (from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/upgrade-table)

Comment: Name of the property is not predefined. If you have added major upgrade from Media > Upgrades section, 
 Installshield would have already created. Check for the ActionProperty column of Upgrade table if it's already created. Otherwise, You can create a custom public property for the upgrade.

Comment: Imagine I am not using Installshield in particular, but rather have a Wix project. I can add a condition for an Upgrade table which, for example, sets an `OLD_PRODUCT_DETECTED` property if the condition is true. Will the Product Code be appended to the property resulting in `OLD_PRODUCT_DETECTED_{GUID}`? If so, *How would I access it programmaticaly within the custom action*?

Comment: Irrespective of which tool is being used, OLD_PRODUCT_DETECTED property value will be set to {GUID} (Product Code of existing installed version). It will not be appended to property name.

Comment: Can you add this to your answer, so I can accept it?